# @Pattern for String- Java bean validation

Tags: regex

My bean have a field called name. I need to do a validation that Name should not contain (), (`.`), (`,`), (`-`), (`/`), (`‘`), (`@`).

I tried this but it did not work.I need help.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^(?!.*( \\s |.|,|-|/|@|' )).*$",message="should not contain ( ), (.), (,), (-), (/), (‘), (@)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Character Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) (**`negation`**) here instead of a *Negative Lookahead*.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[^ .,‘/@-]*$")
```

It's not clear if (`'`) should be added since you contain it in your regular expression above but you do not specify that this character should not be contained.

The following might work for you as well depending on how *strict* this name field should be..

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, I agree that some flavor of option 2 would be sensible, otherwise he might exclude all these chars and still end up with ประเทศไทย :)